# Communicate between Voice and Data VLAN

Tags: router, switch, vlan, voice

I have a network of computers, on which I also have an Avaya IP Office phone system with several IP phones. Currently the IP phones are on their own IP subnet range, but I want to create a separate Voice and Data VLAN.

Currently the network is connected through a Zyxel ES-2024 layer 2 switch. This is connected to a Draytek layer 3 router, which is the default gateway in the network. Since the Zyxel supports multiple VLANs I think I am basically okay with creating multiple VLANs with it.

Once I have done this, I have a machine (running call recording software) that will need to pick up the voice traffic whilst also be accessible from the data VLAN. **My question is:** If I want this to be the case, is it possible to use the default gateway (Draytek layer 3 router) to facilitate inter-VLAN communication, or will I need a dual network card in the call recorder machine?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which particular Router model do you have?

Comment: It is a Draytek Vigor if that helps. I'm unsure as to the exact model as it is currently at a site where I am not.